# Why aren't dageshes aligned in Hebrew in LuaLaTex?

Tags: luatex, babel, hebrew

I'm trying to typeset a single line of Biblical Hebrew, in which some letters have a *dagesh* diacritic, which is no problem in my text editor in my chosen font (designed for Biblical Hebrew), but for some reason LuaLaTeX is refusing to put the *dagesh* in the proper place.  MWE below, along with example of what should be produced:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{KeterYG-Medium}
\begin{document}
    כָּל-עֲמַל הָאָדָם, לְפִיהוּ; וְגַם-הַנֶּפֶשׁ, לֹא תִמָּלֵא.
\end{document}
```

[image]
Whereas this is what should be produced:

[image]

Comment: No time to investigate, but it looks like all the nikkudim are misaligned. I notice you haven’t actually specified Hebrew as the main language vía Babel or otherwise identified the text as Hebrew

Comment: Did you try with [Renderer=Harfbuzz]?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thank you!

Comment: @DonHosek Good job spotting that—embarassingly, I had uploaded the wrong code (the screenshot was, of course, produced by the correct specifying Hebrew because otherwise TeX would render it backwards!))  Fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the comment advice together (language selection, plus font rendering) gives:

[image: languageplusfont]

with various fonts.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{CMU Serif}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Path=C:/Users/Public/fonts/1/,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Medium,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
]{KeterYG}
%
\babelfont[hebrew]{ivrtshfr}[Path=C:/Users/Public/fonts/1/,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*Regular,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
]{Shofar}
%
\babelfont[hebrew]{ivrtdvd}[Path=C:/Users/Public/fonts/1/,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Medium,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
]{TaameyDavidCLM}
%
\babelfont[hebrew]{ivrtash}[Path=C:/Users/Public/fonts/1/,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Medium,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
]{TaameyAshkenaz}
%
\babelfont[hebrew]{ivrttfc}[Path=C:/Users/Public/fonts/1/,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Medium,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
]{TaameyFrankCLM}
%
\babeltags{hebrew=hebrew}
%
\begin{document}

{
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\colorbox{blue!8}{\texthebrew{כָּל-עֲמַל הָאָדָם, לְפִיהוּ; וְגַם-הַנֶּפֶשׁ, לֹא תִמָּלֵא.}}
}

{
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\textivrtshfr{כָּל-עֲמַל הָאָדָם, לְפִיהוּ; וְגַם-הַנֶּפֶשׁ, לֹא תִמָּלֵא.}
}

{
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\textivrtash{כָּל-עֲמַל הָאָדָם, לְפִיהוּ; וְגַם-הַנֶּפֶשׁ, לֹא תִמָּלֵא.}
}

{
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\textivrtdvd{כָּל-עֲמַל הָאָדָם, לְפִיהוּ; וְגַם-הַנֶּפֶשׁ, לֹא תִמָּלֵא.}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!